# How can someone handle default datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, data-formats

I have DAL where I convert database null value to their equivalent representation in C#. For example:

```
NULL for Numeric = 0
NULL for String = String.Empty
NULL for DateTime = "1/1/0001" (i.e. DateTime.MinValue)
```

The problem, for date, lies in the presentation layer, especially in GridViews. You cannot show `1/1/01` to users.

What I used to do is check `if myDate.Year=1 or myDate.Year < AcceptedDate` and display empty string, but seems to be extra effort unlike other types

Please am open to better approach. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just adjust the format of the Date Column so that instead of showing 1/1/01 (which is assumed to be 2001) it will show the actual value which is 1/1/0001. That or possible convert the date to a string when it is entered so that it doesn't try and change the date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Nullable` datatype to store null value.

```
DateTime? value = null;
int? myNullableInt = 1;
value = DateTime.Now;
```

How to check whether variable has value or null

```
if (value!=null)
```

String value can store null, so there is no diffrent datatype for string to store null.

```
string var;
if (var == null)
```

or

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(var))
```

Comment: +1. When checking for null, either that or `value.HasValue`, whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: In addition, you could repeat this pattern throughout your treatment of value types, i.e. NULL for SQLInt could be `int? default = null;`.  As a side note, strings are actually reference types, and can be assigned the value `null`.

Comment: I agree. Nullable types are better for this. Why I did not consider this approach is because those fields are required in my DB. But making them nullable in my Business Logic means I have to check value before passing the to DB

Comment: if you don't check for null then null will be updated in the database. What you want to do if these fields has null value.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use DateTime.MinValue constant.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx

Your conditions would be:

```
if (myDate == DateTime.MinValue)
```

Comment: painful when you have to do this in a GridView. Then you will have to use TemplateField instead of BoundField

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Nullable` `DateTime`, so you will return `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` from your DAL. This way you can check if returned value is null.

```
DateTime? dateTime = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others mention, you could use a `System::Nullable<DateTime>`.

The other approach I've seen is to use a standard `DateTime` and just use a special value such as `DateTime.MinValue`.  This is useful if you need to honor an existing interface's types and can't change the `DateTime` to a `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Comment: DateTime.MinValue = 1/1/01. It's the same thing.

Comment: yes, but it's a defined field.  it's trivial for the grid to check for equality between DateTime.MinValue and whatever the DAL is giving back

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a Nullable DateTime as the others suggested, or use this trick:
(To prevent non valid defaults.)

```
// If dateTime has not been initialize, initialize to Now
// (or to any other legal inital values)
dateTime = ((dateTime != new DateTime()) ? dateTime : DateTime.Now);
```

This trick is useful if you have to use a non-nullable DateTime and want to provide a default if none. (E.g. you have a non-nullable DateTime column in a DB and want to set the value only if row is new.)

Comment: Note: `new DateTime()` is the same as `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: @HansKesting Interesting, since it appears to be an invalid date for some systems. (From MSDN: "The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001." --> must be out of range for some systems.)

Comment: SqlServer will not accept this date (will reject dates before 1753 IIRC)

Comment: "If I Recall Correctly" - I'm not 100% sure about that 1753, but it's something like that

Comment: So you can't use SqlServer's built in types in databases for historic information :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have much choice but to make the check like you have been and display accordingly. A nullable type might make things easier for you. Depending on your data, even the numeric should be treated this way. DBNull != 0.